# How to hide access key when serving html from was s3?

Tags: html, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have a website that is served from was s3. The website makes an ajax post request to an api gateway, whenever the user fills out the contact form and hits the submit button.

For the api I am planning to make restricted with access key. Where should I put the access key, so it is not exposed?

Would appreciate detailed answers.